# why the second request.session cookies return empty?

Tags: python, web-scraping, session-cookies

I want to log in to a website with requests.Session.post. But when I had already the homepage login, and then go into the account page. It seems the cookies had not saved, because the cookies are empty. And I can not get to the right account page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'
                        'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                        'Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
          'origin': 'https://selma.tu-dresden.de'
          }


logdata = {
            'usrname': '******',
            'pass': '******',
            'APPNAME': 'CampusNet',
            'PRGNAME': 'LOGINCHECK',
            'ARGUMENTS': 'clino,usrname,pass,menuno,menu_type,browser,platform',
            'clino': '000000000000001',
            'menuno': '000155',
            'menu_type': 'Classic',
            'browser':'',
            'platform':''
           }

# post log in data

session = requests.Session()
post_url = 'https://selma.tu-dresden.de/APP'
html = session.post(post_url, data=logdata, headers=header)
print(html.status_code)
print(html.cookies)

# check if we already log in

rout = 'https://selma.tu-dresden.de/APP/EXTERNALPAGES/-N904200466705967,-N000108,-AEXT_Bewerbung'
konto_html = requests.get(rout, allow_redirects=False, cookies=html.cookies)
print(konto_html.cookies)
```

the result is:

```
200
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie ARRAffinity=f220f466b0cc86d57e60f7469bcce5940d9291ac90e2d500fa9a70c1375769a2 for .selma.tu-dresden.de/>, <Cookie cnsc=5FCB07D7E3960C2309380EF88E0684AE for selma.tu-dresden.de/>]>
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

In fact, I did not log in my account, because in the html.text show that

```
<title>Zugang verweigert
```

It means failure.

I don't know why.

Comment: Use `session.get()` and print `session.cookies`.

Comment: I try to use the session.get() and get something, but the content is the same as the session.post.

Comment: Session collects and store all cookies automatically, so you don't need to pass cookies as argument. Same with headers, you can assign it once to `session.headers` and it will be used for all requests in that session.

Comment: so why I can't get the login page information after using 'session.get()',still failed

Answer (score 0):

The URL, that you are routing to, has arguments. The first one "-N904200466705967" is the session ID. You are trying to rout to another session. This is why you aren't routing to that site and the web application is denying you access.

Here is a [Code Snippet](https://selma.tu-dresden.de/js/skripts.js), of how submitting the form creates the URL, you are redirected to.

```js
    reloadpage = {
        submitForm:function(formName){
            /*function to submit a form, without editing the reload params*/
            var form = document.getElementById(formName);
            
            if (form != null)
            {
                $('input[name="Refresh"]').attr("disabled",true);
                $('input[name="Refresh"]').addClass("cnm_disabled");            
                form.submit();
            }
        },
        
        createUrlAndReload:function(dispatcher, applicationName, programName, sessionNo, menuId,args){
            var temp_args;
            if(args!=''){ temp_args =','+args};
        
            $('input[name="Refresh"]').attr("disabled",true);
            $('input[name="Refresh"]').addClass("cnm_disabled");
            window.location.href = dispatcher + "?APPNAME=" + applicationName + "&PRGNAME=" + programName + "&ARGUMENTS=-N" + sessionNo + ",-N" + menuId  + temp_args;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Please avoid from using images (explanation [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)) and instead post the code in textual format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).