# Python Web Scraping Login with Cookies is always throwing an access denied error

Tags: python, web-scraping

currently I'm trying to write a Python Code with which one I can check my grades at a portal of my university. Therefore is a csnc cookie essential. I found an example which is similar to the page I want to access with my tool:

[why the second request.session cookies return empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64623360/why-the-second-request-session-cookies-return-empty)

However, I can get the cookie from the page but when I want to access the main page I always receive "access denied". I don't know exactly where my mistake is...

My Code is the following part:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'
                        'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                        'Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
          'origin': 'https://dualis.dhbw.de',
          'referer': 'https://dualis.dhbw.de/'
          }


payload = {
            'usrname': 'xxx',
            'pass': 'xxx',
            'APPNAME': 'CampusNet',
            'PRGNAME': 'LOGINCHECK',
            'ARGUMENTS': 'clino,usrname,pass,menuno,menu_type,browser,platform',
            'clino': '000000000000001',
            'menuno': '000324',
            'menu_type': 'classic',
            'browser':'',
            'platform':''
           }


session = requests.Session()
post_url = 'https://dualis.dhbw.de/scripts/mgrqispi.dll'
#html = session.get(post_url, data=payload, headers=header, cookies=session.cookies)
html = session.post(post_url, headers = header, data = payload, cookies=session.cookies)
print(html.status_code)
print(html.cookies)


rout = 'https://dualis.dhbw.de/scripts/mgrqispi.dll?APPNAME=CampusNet&PRGNAME=EXTERNALPAGES&ARGUMENTS=-N000000000000001,-N000324,-Awelcome'
konto_html = requests.post(rout, data = payload,  headers = header, allow_redirects=True, cookies=html.cookies)
konto_html = requests.get(rout)
print(konto_html.text)
```

The grades are on this page:

https://dualis.dhbw.de/scripts/mgrqispi.dll?APPNAME=CampusNet&PRGNAME=COURSERESULTS&ARGUMENTS=-N960367902774247,-N000307,

But when I access I always get as already mentioned an error

Maybe somebody can give me a hint how I can continue here that I can access this page :)

Answer (score -1):

The URL https://dualis.dhbw.de/scripts/mgrqispi.dll?APPNAME=CampusNet&PRGNAME=COURSERESULTS&ARGUMENTS=-N960367902774247,-N000307 has arguments.

- `-N960367902774247` is the session id
- `-N000307` is the menu id

The session id is an id that changes when the session changes, which is why your access is denied.